# Why a simple index is not working in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

I have a simple table and some sample data

```
create table test_index (
    id serial primary key,
    name char(255)
);
insert into test_index (name) values ('tom');
insert into test_index (name) values ('john');
insert into test_index (name) values ('ken');
```

After created the table and data, I created an index for **name** column

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test_index_shop_name ON test_index(name);
```

But when I do the simple query on **name** column

```
select * from test_index where name = 'tom';
```

Its not using the index, just scan through the whole table
[image]

It seems a simple thing, but I can't figure out why its not working, does anyone know what is the cause of it?

**Update 1**

I see the answer suggest this is small data hence it doesn't use index, so I can understand why its not using it here.

But I have the similar setup with the a char(255) column and added index of that column, but the table have 16 millions rows, and it also didn't use the index created, anyone know why?

**Update 2**

Here is the actual table with index but not using it when querying the table

[image]

Here is the verbose output

[image]

Comment: With just 3 rows (and you requesting all the columns) an index is a waste of time

Comment: You realize an index is not magic? That it is basically an auxiliary look table that incurs overhead when doing said lookup and that as consequence the faster solution for a small number of rows is a sequential scan.

Comment: It's working great, the database selects the best and fastest query plan: A sequential read on the table, ignoring any index.

Comment: Unrelated, but: [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: This is an example of a larger table that I have 16 millions rows, its have similar setup and its still not using the index, hence to scale down data in here

Comment: @vitohuang Share your query plan over here, in your question that is, using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)

Comment: @FrankHeikens I've attached the query plan, but I don't know what's the buffers and how to use it, let me know if you can give me examples

Comment: You did an EXPLAIN, not the EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) SELECT ... What you already see is that the planner expects to find millions of rows, not just a few ones. Maybe you need some changes to the table statistics, but first you need EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)

Comment: @FrankHeikens thanks for that, I've attached analyze verbose output, but I'm not sure about the EXPLAIN BUFFERS, as you can see from my screenshot, its not valid statement. As from the above its taking almost 1 minutes for the query and it doesn't seems to using index at all

Comment: You left the ( and ) out, check my comments. The query has to find almost 5 million rows and can skip 11 million rows. I don’t think an index scan would be faster

Comment: @FrankHeikens I reread your previous comments, and still I'm not sure what do you mean by the left ( and ) out, can you give me an example? For the index, I'm not sure its why its not using index at all, and it seems a bit slow need to wait almost 1 minutes to get the result on a not massive database, do you know anyway to speed it up?

Answer (score 1):

The planner is estimating that with just three rows, it will be faster to pull the three rows from the heap (table). If it doesn't, it will go to the index, finding the matching pointers in the heap (table) and then go to the table to retrieve the data, making it slower. If you look at the example below, you will see that using the index is actually slower.

```
create table test_index (
id serial primary key,
name char(255)
);

insert into test_index (name) values ('tom');
insert into test_index (name) values ('john');
insert into test_index (name) values ('ken');
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1

CREATE INDEX idx_test_index_shop_name ON test_index(name);
CREATE INDEX



Seq Scan on test_index  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=1 width=1028) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: (name = 'tom'::bpchar)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 2
 Planning Time: 0.324 ms
 Execution Time: 0.032 ms

set enable_seqscan to off;

Index Scan using idx_test_index_shop_name on test_index  (cost=0.13..8.15 rows=1 width=1028) (actual time=0.044..0.046 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (name = 'tom'::bpchar)
 Planning Time: 0.065 ms
 Execution Time: 0.072 ms
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I can see why its not using index in this situation, but this is an example of a larger table that I have 16 millions rows, its have similar setup and its still not using the index, hence to scale down data in here. BTW how did you force it to use index in your result above?

Comment: @vitohuang: Share your query plan over here, in your question that is, using EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)

Comment: @FrankHeikens I've attached the query plan, but I don't know what's the buffers and how to use it, let me know if you can give me examples

Comment: If you have 16 million rows, please provide an EXPLAIN ANALYZE query... I have a guess but I need to see the results of that plan.

Comment: @JoshuaD.Drake will be good to see what you think? btw I've added more verbose explain analyze